# Codeigniter and insert_batch from explode

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have this code:

```
    function insertGenre() {
    $genres = explode(',',$this->input->post('genreName'));

    foreach($genres as $genre) {
        $temp = array(
            'id' => null,
            'name' => $genre,
            'popular' => '0'
        );

        $data2[] =  $temp;
    }

    return $data2;

    $data = array(
        'id' => null,
        'name' => $this->input->post('genreName'),
        'popular' => '0'
    );

    //$this->db->insert('genres',$data);
    $this->db->insert_batch('genres',$data2);
}
```

It should run just fine (I ran through a couple of questions in here), but it doesn't. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is it supposed to do? What do you expect as output? What does it actually do? [What have you tried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)?

Comment: Also, you **do** realize that your function `returns` `$data2` and never executes the lines below it, don't you?

Comment: Refresh yourself on what [`return`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php) does. (That's a link, BTW).

Comment: If you want to be sure that a line of code is executing, it's easy enough to just add an `echo` statement before and after it, if only for debugging purposes (you always have the power to remove them later).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't it be something like this:

```
function insertGenre() {
    $genres = explode(',',$this->input->post('genreName'));

    foreach($genres as $genre) {
        $temp = array(
            'id' => null,
            'name' => $genre,
            'popular' => '0'
        );
        $data2[] =  $temp;
    }

    if( $this->db->insert_batch('genres',$data2) ) {
        return $data2;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

You were returning before you ran the insert query. The second `$data` variable also seems to be redundant.

I also added the if statement at the end which will return false if the insert fails.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move your `return` to the end of the function, otherwise it will never execute the lines below it:

```
function insertGenre() {
    $genres = explode(',',$this->input->post('genreName'));

    foreach($genres as $genre) {
        $temp = array(
            'id' => null,
            'name' => $genre,
            'popular' => '0'
        );

        $data2[] =  $temp;
    }

    $data = array(
        'id' => null,
        'name' => $this->input->post('genreName'),
        'popular' => '0'
    );

    //$this->db->insert('genres',$data);
    $this->db->insert_batch('genres',$data2);

    return $data2;
}
```